# iOS8 Text view scrolls text down when presented in a controller using autolayout and size classes

Tags: uitextview, autolayout, xcode6, uistoryboard, size-classes

I have a view controller laid out in a storyboard using size classes and autolayout. I've added a couple pages of text inside the text view. When I present the controller containing this text view using form sheet style on iPad, the text within the textview is scrolled down, cutting out first 4-5 lines.

**How can I make sure that UITextView rearranges it's contents so first line of text is displayed at the top (where it is expected to be)?**

Here's what I see in storyboard. When presented, the word "test" is hidden off the top of the textview (where the word play is).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug with size classes, but here is a workaround:

If your scene in storyboard is bigger than on the device (simulated metrics "freeform"), the auto layout will size down the view and changes the scrolling of the text view.

If you preview the scene with the smallest simulated metrics (iPhone 3.5-inch landscape!), the text view will keep size or grow and the scrolling is ok.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: But I had the same problem, which is having a UITextView with very long text and its size bigger in storyboard than on runtime. It can be easily reproduced with a single-view test project. The problem is, that the text view doesn't keep the first line on the top when getting resized (which happens on layout). My solution avoids this, because the text view doesn't get smaller on first layout.